# How to uniquely identify a place on Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

i'm developing a web app that uses the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. I've this problem: I would to save a place in my DB using Places Autocomplete. The user, type a place into a text field and then, after a call vs the API, my application should check if a the city of the selected place exists in my DB; if true, return the city ID, otherwise insert the city and return last inserted ID.

To do this, I need to uniquely identify a place. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying to work around the issue of saving the same place autocompleted in two languages. ie: "London" (en) and "Londres" (es) have the same id. I'd like to store only the real name "London" not based on the user's "locale user agent"

Comment: As of 2018 there is a unique identifier for each place in the API: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The PlaceResult given by Places API contains an identifier. You can't use it as a unique id cause it can change as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=es#PlaceResult)

That's a place result for "London, United Kingdom" from a ES (Spanish) browser:

```
address_components: Array[4]
formatted_address: "Londres, Reino Unido"
geometry: Object
html_attributions: Array[0]
icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"
id: "b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0"
name: "Londres"
reference: "CnRmAAAAxcbYEYZvXgbynu4U43cAtEqvCzpZrJUsDusnrYe2pu9nl0zCjyxdeSBMeTVbYQjzaJc56HEyV-YuSJUXLA0sbJUx-1GcaCEFYYX0HSQqXXoId3u_KClG9TpxCUyZhS-dJoLOQj1YJbmPcaWiuFM87hIQGOszWwqjaFe0bseLKvsicRoUCadktNXFFSgNAcHrD8LMSZuXbSA"
types: Array[2]
url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Londres&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99"
vicinity: "Londres"
__proto__: Object
```

You should implement some logic to update id's for same place. Haven't found any solution yet for this issue.